# Resharper window shows nothing but background

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

I have installed ReSharper 6.1 and it is integrated in Visual Studio 2008.

When I go to ReSharper menu in VS and click on Option, a window appears and it shows the background (like a transparent glass). it does not show options.

You can see the option window of ReSharper attached

Does anybody know why it is happening.

[image]

Comment: If restarting your VS / computer doesn't fix it, may be worth reporting it here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: thanks for the link , but i guess it will take time , I have only few days left of my registration.

Comment: You can always download an EAP edition, they come with an evaluation key which will allow you to see if it's been fixed, and use it for longer (60 days I think?)

Comment: Saying that, options on 6.1 works fine on my (VS2010 admittedly) machine :-)

Comment: I am already using an evaluation version, does download again work?

Comment: I think the EAPs use their own keys, but looking at their site, they don't have any early access builds for VS2008 available - have you got 6.1.1 installed?

Comment: Hi Imran ! Did you get your problem solved ? Build 6.1.1 doesn't work for me either :(

Comment: @ruslan Yes, after reinstalling it.

Comment: @ImranRizvi, reinstalling Resharper or VS ?

Comment: @ruslan uninstalled Resharper 6.1, then installed new version i.e. 6.1.1. (Please see my comments in accepted answer for more details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any additional plugins or addins installed in yourVS 2008 environment? Please run VS 2008 with the following command key and send me a log file via mail toKirill[dot]Falk@jetbrains[dot]com.

```
devenv.exe /ReSharper.Internal /ReSharper.LogFile C:\FOO.txt /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose
```

Comment: I did the same, please check your email box

Comment: as per your email suggession I reinstall new version i.e. 6.1.1 and it is working fine now.

Comment: Kirill, is there another email where I send log file to ? Neither 6.1.1 nor EAP 7 works for me with VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you either report the issue on [the bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) or download an [Early Access Program](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Early+Access+Program) edition which comes with its own evaluation key.

The EAPs are only available when they have a new version in beta, so may not be available for your version of Visual Studio